# Find $u$ such that $\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x²}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=1$ in $r<a$ and $u=0$ in $r=a$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, linear-pde

> Find  $u$ such that $\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x²}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=1$  in $r<a$ and $u=0$ in $r=a$.

**My attempt**

The equation in polar coordinates is given by:

$$ \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r²}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \theta²} = 1$$

I'm looking for a solution that depends only on $r$. Therefore:

$$ \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r²}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = 1 \Rightarrow r\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial r²}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = r\Rightarrow \frac{\partial (ru)}{\partial r} = r
$$

Integrating twice in $r$, I found that:

$$ u(r,\theta) = \frac{r^2}{4} +  A\ln(r)  + B $$

Applying the boundary condition we get:

$$  \frac{a^2}{4} + A\ln(a) + B = 0 $$

I'm stuck here. I can't find the constants $A$ and $B$. Furthermore, the  solution of this Poisson equation is unique (by maximum principle). It looks like we have a family of solutions. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about $(r^2-a^2)/4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $r \mapsto \ln r$ is not bounded near $r=0$, one has $A=0$.

Now we get 
$$ \frac{a^2}{4} + B = 0$$
so
$$ B = - \frac{a^2}{4}$$.